# Bot that sends automated reminder messages/emails/whatsapps

Tags: email, automation

I'm trying to create some sort of Bot that sends me automated reminder mails on my email account or text message on my phone.

Where I live, trash gets collected according to the trash type (e.g. plastic, paper etc.). So let's say every second Monday paper trash gets collected. Often times i forget to take the trash out though so I want to create some sort of bot that reminds me on my phone.

I'm really not sure where to start looking for possible solutions. Will Microsoft Azure and its services be a viable option?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Why not just use the calendar on your 'phone? Set alarms?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [IFTT](https://ifttt.com/) (**I**f-**T**his-**T**hen-**T**hat) might be something that you're looking for. Especially to use it for for getting relevant [reminders](https://ifttt.com/search/query/reminders). Here is a quote from its [about](https://ifttt.com/about) page:

> IFTTT is a free platform that helps you do more with all your apps and devices

PS: haven't found a way yet to make something like this to work:

<kbd>If</kbd> there is some sort of activity for any of my SE-posts (comments, votes, revisions, deleted, whatever)

<kbd>then</kbd> send an eMail to the eMail account I configured in my profile of the relevant SE site.

Comment: Your answer is ok. Probably should have explained how to set it up. Your P.S. should be a separate question.